# HTML5 accessing a full column to hide it via javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have to hide a full column (1 TH and multiple TDs)  how to do this with HTML 5 involved?

In the past I used "Name" there to Name all columns that I wanted to be able to hide in one go the same by iterating over `document.GetElementsByName("MyColumnName")` and then Setting Display to None.

How is this now done in HTML5 as the Name property is no longer valid for th nor td.

Comment: It's common practice to use css classes. With document.getElementsByClassName or jQuery: $(".my-class")...

Answer (score 1):

use `id` attribute and `document.getElementById('idOfElement')` function, which returns element *(not array)* with the given id. Or `class` attribute and `document.getElementsByClassName('myClassName')` which returns elements with class attribute equal to 'myClassName'.

Answer (score 0):

You could still iterate over all instances of a `th` with a certain id or class name. While using jQuery to do this as the better alternative, you could also still use the name tag and loop over elements by tag name.

Some examples would be:

HTML:

```
<td class="foo"></td>
<td id="foo"></td>
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
// get element by class name
$(".foo").each(function(){
    $(this).css("display", "none");
});

// get element by id
$("#foo").each(function(){
    $(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

**Using JavaScript:**

```
// get by class name
var foo = getElementsByClassName("foo");

for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
}

// get by id
var foo = getElementById("foo");

for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
}
```

**Full example:**

It is recommended that you use a `class` name rather than an `id` as an `id` should always be unique while there can be multiple instances of `class` name.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th></th>
            <td class="foo"></td>
            <td class="foo"></td>
            <td class="foo"></td>
        </table>
    </body>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".foo").each(function(){
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to select a certain element. Assuming the TH is the third TH in the table, you could select it via

```
document.querySelector("th:nth-of-type(3)")
```

and then apply style.display... to it.
But without the Markup it's difficult to give a definite answer.